# Run TensorFlow in a for loop

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, parallel-processing, cpu-usage

I have a for loop in my code and in each iteration I augment some processed data and train my TF model again. After a while it takes longer than expected to process my code. I suspect about CPU usage since I running on multiple cores. How can I fix that?

Comment: add some relevant code.

Comment: I cannot share the code here. But generally there is a for loop and at each iteration I train a model. BTW, I'm coding in Python.